# Failing to run Mattermost locally on a Kubernetes cluster using Minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, nginx-ingress, mattermost

**Summary in one sentence**

I want to deploy Mattermost locally on a Kubernetes cluster using Minikube

**Steps to reproduce**

I used this tutorial and the Github documentation:

- https://mattermost.com/blog/how-to-get-started-with-mattermost-on-kubernetes-in-just-a-few-minutes/
- https://github.com/mattermost/mattermost-operator/tree/v1.15.0

1. To start minikube: `minikube start --kubernetes-version=v1.21.5`
2. To start ingress; `minikube addons enable ingress`
3. I cloned the Github repo with tag v1.15.0 (second link)
4. In the Github documentation (second link) they state that you need to install Custom Resources by running: `kubectl apply -f ./config/crd/bases`
5. Afterwards I installed MinIO and MySQL operators by running: `make mysql-minio-operators`
6. Started the Mattermost-operator locally by running: `go run .`
7. In the end I deployed Mattermost (I followed step 2, 7 and 9 from the first link)

**Observed behavior**

Unfortunately I keep getting the following error in the mattermost-operator:

```golang
INFO[1419] [opr.controllers.Mattermost] Reconciling Mattermost  Request.Name=mm-demo Request.Namespace=mattermost
INFO[1419] [opr.controllers.Mattermost] Updating resource  Reconcile=fileStore Request.Name=mm-demo Request.Namespace=mattermost kind="&TypeMeta{Kind:,APIVersion:,}" name=mm-demo-minio namespace=mattermost patch="{\"status\":{\"availableReplicas\":0}}"
INFO[1419] [opr.controllers.Mattermost.health-check] mattermost pod not ready: pod mm-demo-ccbd46b9c-9nq8k is in state 'Pending'  Request.Name=mm-demo Request.Namespace=mattermost
INFO[1419] [opr.controllers.Mattermost.health-check] mattermost pod not ready: pod mm-demo-ccbd46b9c-tp567 is in state 'Pending'  Request.Name=mm-demo Request.Namespace=mattermost
ERRO[1419] [opr.controllers.Mattermost] Error checking Mattermost health  Request.Name=mm-demo Request.Namespace=mattermost error="found 0 updated replicas, but wanted 2"
```

By using k9s I can see that mm-demo won't start. See below for photo.

[image]

---

## Another variation of deployment

Also tried another variation by following all the steps from the first link (without the licences secret step). At this point the mattermost-operator is visible using k9s and won't getting any errors. But unfortunately the mm-demo pod keeps crashing (empty logs, so seeing no errors or something).
Anybody an idea?

Comment: I reproduced this on my GKE environment using [doc](https://mattermost.com/blog/how-to-get-started-with-mattermost-on-kubernetes-in-just-a-few-minutes/) and faced the same issue. The “mm-demo” Service deployment kept failing with an error “Cannot schedule pods: Insufficient cpu.”. I was able to resolve this by upgrading the Machine type(no. of vCPUs and Memory) of VM instances that are part of the GKE cluster. I’d suggest you [upgrade](https://www.shellhacks.com/minikube-start-with-more-memory-cpus/) the Cluster’s Node resources. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ashish faced the same issue, he fixed it by upgrading the resources.

Minikube will be able to run all the pods by running `minikube start --kubernetes-version=v1.21.5 --memory 4000 --cpus 4`